# What is the name of the declaration "int (*p)[SIZE]" that distinguishes it from "int *p[SIZE]"?

Tags: c

The first declaration is commonly referred to as an array of pointers.  Does the second declaration have a name or description that distinguishes it from the first declaration?

Declaration 1: `int *p[SIZE]`

Declaration 2: `int (*p)[SIZE]`

Comment: The second is a *pointer to an array* (of size `SIZE`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p is array of int pointers.

```
int *p[SIZE]
```

p is pointer to an array of integers

```
 int (*p)[SIZE]
```

**Edit**

The second kind of declaration is mentioned in **5.12 Complicated Declarations** The C programming Language book.
Here is some reference which explains [complicated declarations](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)

Comment: Entity 1: array of pointers, and Entity 2: pointer to an array.  That's what I wanted to know.  Thanks.

Comment: @adpatter glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int *p[SIZE]
```

This is to declare array of `SIZE` number of pointers to `int`

Whereas , this -

```
int (*p)[SIZE]
```

declare `p` as pointer to array of int (having `SIZE` number of elements)